# Ask user if he wants to turn on the Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Now my program just reads, if it is enabled/disabled.
If enabled, there goes alert - "Geolocation disabled". Is there any way I can enable it through Javascript?

For example: "Geolocation disabled. Do you want to turn it on?"
And Geolocation enables.

Answer (score 0):

When you will seek for user's location browser will automatically ask for sharing location with web site, there is no other way that this

i.e. When you will write below code, browsers(FF, Chrome or IE) will prompt a popup which will ask user for sharing location information

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
function showPosition(position) {
  console.log(position);
}
```